# Склонение существительных в javascript-таймере

Tags: javascript

От предыдущего владельца сайта мне достался следующий код, отсчитывающий время от определенной даты. Код работает, но при этом в нем отсутствуют склонения у дней и часов. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKZEMB

```
   window.onload=function() {
  // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
  upTime('feb,14,2018,14:00:00'); 
}
function upTime(countTo) {
  now = new Date();
  countTo = new Date(countTo);
  difference = (now-countTo);

  days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
  hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);

  document.getElementById('days').firstChild.nodeValue = days;
  document.getElementById('hours').firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
  document.getElementById('minutes').firstChild.nodeValue = mins;
  document.getElementById('seconds').firstChild.nodeValue = secs;

  clearTimeout(upTime.to);
  upTime.to=setTimeout(function(){ upTime(countTo); },1000);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="countup">
  Прошло
  <p id="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">дней</p> и
  <p id="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">часов</p>
</div>
```

Сам я в javascript абсолютно ничего не понимаю, но этот момент очень сильно режет глаза. Буду благодарен за решение проблемы. Пытался самостоятельно адаптировать этот код https://gist.github.com/realmyst/1262561 но потерпел неудачу

Comment: а у минут и секунд склонения есть?

Comment: Они не выводятся в хтмл коде, но не склоняются

Comment: а где находятся слова "день/дня/дней"?

Comment: Вот код https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKZEMB 
Продублирую сейчас в тексте вопроса

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не менять Ваш код, то пример "в лоб":

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Month,Day,Year,Hour,Minute,Second
  upTime('feb,14,2018,14:00:00');
}

function upTime(countTo) {
  now = new Date();
  countTo = new Date(countTo);
  difference = (now - countTo);

  days = Math.floor(difference / (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24) * 1);
  hours = Math.floor((difference % (60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)) / (60 * 60 * 1000) * 1);

  document.getElementById('days').firstChild.nodeValue = days;
  document.getElementById('hours').firstChild.nodeValue = hours;

  document.querySelector('.timeRefDays').textContent =
    (days == 1 || (days > 19 && days % 10 == 1)) ? 'день' :
    ((days > 1 && days < 5) || (days > 19 && days % 10 > 1 && days % 10 < 5)) ? 'дня' : 'дней';

  document.querySelector('.timeRefHours').textContent =
    (hours == 1 || (hours > 19 && hours % 10 == 1)) ? 'час' :
    ((hours > 1 && hours < 5) || (hours > 19 && hours % 10 > 1 && hours % 10 < 5)) ? 'часа' : 'часов';

  clearTimeout(upTime.to);
  upTime.to = setTimeout(function() {
    upTime(countTo);
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="countup">
  Прошло
  <p id="days">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefDays">дней</p> и
  <p id="hours">00</p>
  <p class="timeRefHours">часов</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, стало лучше чем сейчас у меня, но всё-равно проскакивают конструкции вроде "141 дней"

Comment: `innerText` лучше не использовать - есть же `textContent`

Comment: @n000000b прошу прощения - отнесся без должного внимания, не потестил. Код поправил, проверил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, смотря где. У них просто есть отличия.

Comment: @Qwerty_Wasd, да, отличия есть, но не при присваивании. Ну и при чтении `textContent` в 99% случаев не нужен.

Comment: `11 день` - что-то здесь не то. `(days<9&&days==1)` - классное условие.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да это понятно :) Но конкретно для этого примера с этой версткой, это незначительный фактор. Только и всего.

Comment: @Igor поправил. Благодарю, не углядел.

Comment: + Это от меня =)

Comment: @Kosta B, благодарю :)

Comment: @Kosta B, сократил маленько код только что.

Comment: Там в сниппете есть кнопка привести в порядок, добавит читабельность.

Comment: @Kosta B, готово